# How to force rsyslog ommysql use utf8?

Tags: mysql, linux, utf-8, rsyslog

I'm using ommysql in rsyslog for transfering data into mysql

```
$ModLoad ommysql
local6.*        :ommysql:localhost,Syslog,rsyslog,1
```

but cyrilic data goes like "·Ð¾Ð²Ð°Ð½Ð¸Ðµ Ð¸Ñ�Ñ‚Ð¾Ñ‡Ð½Ð" in database.

I think It's because ommysql doesn't set utf8 encoding and starts inserting at once it's connected: http://s017.radikal.ru/i441/1606/e0/050cf30c495f.png

Is it any way to say «set names utf8;» before inserting?

Comment: This is not a programming question.  You may want to try  http://serverfault.com/questions  or    http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions

Answer (score -1):

That should have said something like `ование`, correct?

When trying to use utf8/utf8mb4, if you see **Mojibake**, check the following.
This discussion applies to **Double Encoding**, which is not necessarily visible.

- The bytes to be stored need to be utf8-encoded.
- The connection when `INSERTing` and `SELECTing` text needs to specify utf8 or utf8mb4.
- The column needs to be declared `CHARACTER SET utf8` (or utf8mb4).
- HTML should start with `<meta charset=UTF-8>`.